# unable to run 'make inventory" output as everytime it throws error: /bin/sh: json2yaml: command not found

Tags: json, ansible, yaml, terraform

After running terraform script am running make inventroy command to get the output in all.yml file to prepare the yml file to run ansible script.

following is the "Makemefile"

```
USER = tf-user

all:
    aws2 ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$(USER)*" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
        --output json \
        | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName" -r

z:
    aws2 ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$(USER)-tf-zk" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
        --output json \
        | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName" -r

b:
    aws2 ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$(USER)-tf-broker" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
        --output json \
        | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName" -r

sr:
    aws2 ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$(USER)-tf-sr" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
        --output json \
        | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName" -r

c3:
    aws2 ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$(USER)-tf-c3" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
        --output json \
        | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName" -r

connect:
    aws2 ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$(USER)-tf-connect" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
        --output json \
        | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName" -r

ksql:
    aws2 ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$(USER)-tf-ksql" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
        --output json \
        | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName" -r

hosts:
    aws2 ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$(USER)-tf*" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
        --output json \
        | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName" -r

list-tags:
    aws2 ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$(USER)*" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
        --output json \
        | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[] | [.PublicDnsName, .Tags[]] "

inventory:
    terraform output -json \
        | jq  'to_entries[] | {(.key): {hosts: .value.value}} ' \
        | jq -s \
        | json2yaml \
        | sed 's/ - / /g' \
        | sed 's/ "/ /g' \
        | sed 's/"/:/g'

ping:
    ansible -i hosts.yml all -m ping

go:
    ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml ../cp-ansible-aws-nonprod-cp-61/all.yml

cntpart:
    kafka-topics --bootstrap-server ec2-204-236-254-140.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092  --describe | grep PartitionCount |  egrep -o 'PartitionCount: [0-9]*' | egrep -o '\d+' | awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'
```

after running this command : make inventory

getting following error;

```
terraform output -json \
        | jq  'to_entries[] | {(.key): {hosts: .value.value}} ' \
        | jq -s \
        | json2yaml \
        | sed 's/ - / /g' \
        | sed 's/ "/ /g' \
        | sed 's/"/:/g'
/bin/sh: json2yaml: command not found
```

How can i get rid of this error, I tried to run this command ;pip install python-json2yaml to install in my mac and it successfully installed but no different result

Comment: You should install `python-json2yaml` OS wide, or under user which your ansible executes.

Comment: Ansible inventory files can be JSON, and YAML is also a superset of JSON, so even naming the JSON file `.yaml` would work just fine, but I'm guessing based on that series of pipes "optimization" wasn't one of the requirements